# How to scroll in New tab in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I opened a new tab by clicking something in selenium in c #. I want to scroll after changing to a new tab, but I get a timeout error.

I get a timeout message and no scroll.

this is c# code.

Used Chrome 79

Chrome option is

```
options.AddArguments("handlesAlerts=false");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
            options.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-background-networking");
            options.AddArguments("--disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages");
            options.AddArguments("--dns-prefetch-disable");
            options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
            options.AddArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list");
            options.AddArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors");
            options.AddArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
            options.AddArguments("lang=ko_KR");


if (this.driver.WindowHandles.Count > 1)
{
this.driver.SwitchTo().Window(this.driver.WindowHandles[1]);
}
Utils.sleep(3000);
((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,500);");
```

Comment: Thank you. When the code runs, a timeout occurs and the script cannot run.((IJavaScriptExecutor)this.driver).ExecuteScript("window.scrollBy(0,500);");

Comment: Can you ensure that you are on the newly opened tab before you invoke `scroll()`?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. The new tab has a scroll.

Comment: Are you sure Selenium's focus is on the new TAB when you are invoking `scrollBy()`

Comment: The new tab has focus. I checked the focus of the web drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by two steps, 
move to the new `tab` and do the `scroll` there.

```
ArrayList<String> AllTabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles()); 
driver.switchTo().window(AllTabs.get(1));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0 , window.innerHeight)");
```

And you can close the tab after you finish.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code it will work fine

```
 //Open link in new tab
 Actions act = new Actions(driver);
 act.KeyDown(Keys.Control).MoveToElement(elementToopenInNewTab).Click().Perform();
 // Switch to new tab
 driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

 //Scroll down in new tab

  IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
  js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");

 //Move to first tab again 
  driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.First());
```

Comment: js.ExecuteScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)"); 

In the code above
'Warning imed out connecting to chrome, retrying ...'
Expressed

Comment: The above mentioned code is 100% working code. there is another issue may be of your chrome driver version. any how code is 100% working at my end

Comment: The chrome version of the current pc is 79.0.3945.117. Chrome Drive's version is 79.0.3945.36.Does this matter?